# how to merge data from a dictionary to a pandas dataframe with certain conditions

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

I have this dictionary which contains cities and their coordinates:

```
{'Rosario': [-60.63932, -32.946819],
'Concordia': [-74.448212, 40.31094],
'Avellaneda': [-58.367439, -34.660179],
'Corrientes': [-58.834099, -27.4806],
'Caballito': [-58.44104, -34.622639],
'Buenos Aires': [-78.497498, -9.12417],
'Paraná': [-60.5238, -31.73197],
'Santa Fé': [-78.14917, 8.65194],
'San Carlos de Bariloche': [-71.30822, -41.145569],
'Mendoza': [-68.827171, -32.890839]}
```

I would like to merge the cities names as a column to a dataframe which also contains coordinates. Is there a way to  do it based on the latitude and longitude condition?

Sample of a dataframe:

[image]

It has similar values on lat and lon. It has coordinates which are only in the dictionary.

Sample of the dataframe (only a few of a lot of columns):

```
        sunset    temp feels_like pressure      lat      lon
0   1659463668   255.3      248.3     1012 -60.6393 -32.9468
1   1659377129  263.67     256.67      984 -60.6393 -32.9468
2   1659290591  258.31     253.58      983 -60.6393 -32.9468
3   1659204054  266.81     262.63      970 -60.6393 -32.9468
4   1659117518  255.42     255.42      979 -60.6393 -32.9468
```

Comment: Can you please provide your dataframe as text, rather than an image? I'm not going to re-write all of your data for testing.

Comment: Something with some variation would be nice, those are all going to match to the same city :')

Comment: sorry for not clarify .the results of that dataframe are a response from a request which contains 10 differents cities and the last 5 days of it's weather. thats why the sample has the same lat and lon @BeRT2me

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please read the edit help re code block format & other formats. Please before publishing look at the formatted version of your post. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 2):

1st step will be to make your dictionary into a dataframe:

```
cities_dict = {'Rosario': [-60.63932, -32.946819], 'Concordia': [-74.448212, 40.31094], 'Avellaneda': [-58.367439, -34.660179], 'Corrientes': [-58.834099, -27.4806], 'Caballito': [-58.44104, -34.622639], 'Buenos Aires': [-78.497498, -9.12417], 'Paraná': [-60.5238, -31.73197], 'Santa Fé': [-78.14917, 8.65194], 'San Carlos de Bariloche': [-71.30822, -41.145569], 'Mendoza': [-68.827171, -32.890839]}

cities = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(cities_dict, 'index', columns=['lat', 'lon'])
print(cities)

# Output:
                               lat        lon
Rosario                 -60.639320 -32.946819
Concordia               -74.448212  40.310940
Avellaneda              -58.367439 -34.660179
Corrientes              -58.834099 -27.480600
Caballito               -58.441040 -34.622639
Buenos Aires            -78.497498  -9.124170
Paraná                  -60.523800 -31.731970
Santa Fé                -78.149170   8.651940
San Carlos de Bariloche -71.308220 -41.145569
Mendoza                 -68.827171 -32.890839
```

---

From there, I think working with these geometrically will be easiest:

`pip install geopandas pygeos`

```
import geopandas as gp

cities = gp.GeoSeries.from_xy(cities.lat, cities.lon)
cities = cities.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'city'})

df['geometry'] = gp.GeoSeries.from_xy(df.lat, df.lon)
df = gp.GeoDataFrame(df)

out = gp.sjoin_nearest(df, cities)
print(out)

# Output:

       sunset    temp  feels_like  pressure      lat      lon                     geometry  index_right     city
0  1659463668  255.30      248.30      1012 -60.6393 -32.9468  POINT (-60.63930 -32.94680)            0  Rosario
1  1659377129  263.67      256.67       984 -60.6393 -32.9468  POINT (-60.63930 -32.94680)            0  Rosario
2  1659290591  258.31      253.58       983 -60.6393 -32.9468  POINT (-60.63930 -32.94680)            0  Rosario
3  1659204054  266.81      262.63       970 -60.6393 -32.9468  POINT (-60.63930 -32.94680)            0  Rosario
4  1659117518  255.42      255.42       979 -60.6393 -32.9468  POINT (-60.63930 -32.94680)            0  Rosario
```

See: [geopandas.sjoin_nearest](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.sjoin_nearest.html)

[image: works for me]

Comment: for some reason I'm having a attributeerror
'AttributeError: type object 'GeoSeries' has no attribute 'from_xy''
in this line : cities = gp.GeoSeries.from_xy(cities.lat, cities.lon)
And the documentation says it is as you writed it

Comment: Qué sé yo... It works for me~